# NOSQL; where did it all start?

Tags: nosql

Is there a "roots" paper/article/conference that "started it all" for NOSQL? Who laid its theoretical foundations, when, where?

To make the question narrow and specific: what are the origins of the "NOSQL" technological idea?

What I want to do: track its evolution and identify the primary functionality that defines such a system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia: [Evolution of database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database#Evolution_of_database_and_DBMS_technology).